# Installed Mingw64 But Cannot Compile 64bit Code

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, compiler-errors

I installed Mingw 64 on Windows 8 64bit.

There is the return after i type `g++ -v`
`C:\Users\Hobo>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.2-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-re
v2/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686
-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw492/i6
86-492-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32
/include/c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=ada
,c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --e
nable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=rele
ase --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-sjl
j-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check -
-disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --
disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as
--with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib
--with-gmp=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw492/p
rerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-min
gw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=
/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pk
gversion='i686-posix-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sour
ceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw492/i686-492-posix-dwarf-rt
_v4-rev2/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c
/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/ming
w492/i686-492-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i
686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' C
PPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/c/mingw492/i686-492-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/opt/lib
-L/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw492/prerequisites/i686-w64-
mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

then i use `g++ x.cpp -m64`
the return is `sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in`

what can i do?

Comment: You seem to have the wrong download.  It should work with the right binaries.

Comment: @deviantfan but i used the `mingw-w64-install` is that wrong?

Comment: And what did you select there?

Comment: @deviantfan i selected `version: 4.9.2 architecture: i686 threads: posix exception: dwarf build-version: 2`

Comment: `architecture: i686` Then what do you expect?